# Mysqli clause not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I am simulating in phpmyadmin the following mysqli clause:

```
UPDATE users SET text_cli2='rgerger' WHERE ((l_source='ES' || l_source2='EN') AND l_target='CA' AND esp='Medical' AND text_cli2='' AND role ='trad_app' AND number_trad='1') LIMIT 1
```

The clause without `number_trad` is working fine and brings one result as expected, but when I add the `number_trad='1'`, 0 results are returned even though I have got a register with a value of "1" in this row.

Do somebody have an idea of why it is not returning it as expected?

Comment: number_trad is integer datatype or varchar ?

Comment: It is an integer

Comment: try the select statement and check if it returns anything : `SELECT text_cli2, 'rgerger' 
FROM users
WHERE ((l_source='ES' || l_source2='EN') 
AND l_target='CA' 
AND esp='Medical' 
AND text_cli2='' ]
AND role ='trad_app' 
AND number_trad='1')`

Comment: Updates don't return results. Change your statement to a SELECT if you wish to get results.

Comment: In phpmyadmin, when you click on "simulate query", you get the message: "found rows:x". Depending on the case, I get a 1 or a 0

Comment: The problem is that the update does not happen at all, or that it happens but zero rows updated are reported?

Comment: @alberzyzz : did you run the `select` as i mentioned in comment above ? what did u get

Comment: @PrabhatG your `select` gave me error. I do not understand the "["  after `text_cli2=''` and the "," after `text_cli2`

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález the update happens but 0 rows are reported. If I run the same query without `AND number_trad=1`, one row is reported

Comment: @alberzyzz : that's a typo :) try : `SELECT text_cli2, 'rgerger' 
FROM users
WHERE ((l_source='ES' || l_source2='EN') 
AND l_target='CA' 
AND esp='Medical' 
AND text_cli2=''
AND role ='trad_app' 
AND number_trad='1') LIMIT 1`

Comment: @PrabhatG 0 rows affected with the `SELECT`

Comment: If don't know whether this is the case but MySQL doesn't actually update the matching row when it detects that new values are identical to old values. It's an optimisation.

Comment: @alberzyzz That means your `number_trad='1'` condition is messed up. Select query should have returned result. Post sample input data for quality answer.

Comment: Not the case, new value is in that case a random 'neriunger', old one is ''